# Styling a list - getting rid of empty space and putting text in the middle of li

Tags: css

Sorry if the question is unclear but I don't know how else to put it. I need to style a list like this:

[image]

And right now it looks like this:

[image]

This is the CSS code:

```
li{
    font-family: courier, monospace;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 30px;
}
ol>li:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #fff;
}
.originalni{
    color: d00;
}
h2{
    font-family: courier, monospace;
}
ol{
    width: 300px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #aaa;
    background-color: #ddd;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

PHP code:

```
echo "<ol>";
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++){
        if ($tabela[$i][2] == "solsejalec"){
            echo "<li class=\"originalni\">".$tabela[$i][1]."</li>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<li>".$tabela[$i][1]."</li>";
        }
    }
echo "</ol>";
```

Could someone help me style it correctly? I need to get rid of the empty space on the left and put the text in the middle of li (vertically). Oh, and ignore the text color, style and family.

Comment: Your markup wouldn't hurt

Comment: @ElendilTheTall sorry, do you mean the code? I edited my question and added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space to the left, is the default padding from the `<ol>`. So `padding:0;` should help. 
To get the text inside the `<li>` vertical in the middle, you should play with `line-height`, usaly you can set the `line-height` the same as the height of the `<li>`. In your case `30px`.

Add these 3 lines in your css. And check the **DEMO** for the result.

```
ol {padding: 0;}
li {
    ...
    line-height:30px;
    padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}
```

This should do it.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wY2m9/1/)**

Comment: No problem! Happy to help. You can play with margin or padding to get it a little bit to the right.